# How come Invoke-WebRequest returns only my IP Address?

Tags: powershell, web

I ran the cmdlet on the site ifconfig.me:

> Invoke-WebRequest ifconfig.me

For the content, I only got my IP address.

Why don't I get the other HTML content on the page, such as the user agent fields, language, etc?

For example,

> Invoke-WebRequest runescape.com

returned all of the HTML on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that [ifconfig.me](https://ifconfig.me) is sensitive to the `User-Agent` string in a request.

By default, per [Microsoft Learn on `Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7.3), the `User-Agent` string sent is “*similar to `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Microsoft Windows 10.0.15063; en-US) PowerShell/6.0.0` with slight variations for each operating system and platform*”.

I tried this using Chrome on Windows, and copied the `User-Agent` string from the result (`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36`).

I then did `Invoke-WebRequest -URI https://ifconfig.me -UserAgent "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"`, and I got a full webpage, not just the IP address.

Comment: Basically, different browsers return different things.

Comment: It's not the browser that returns different things; it's the site, based on the browser's `User-Agent` string. If the site recognizes 'powershell' as a console scripting system, it's reasonable to assume that the script calling the `Invoke-WebRequest` wants the public IP address, unless you use one of the "paths" (see the 'Command Line Interface' section when you visit it with a browser) to retrieve some of the other information.

Comment: For example, when I didn't set `-UserAgent`, but did `Invoke-WebRequest -URI https://ifconfig.me/ua`, the returned `.Content` was `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT; Windows NT 10.0; en-US) WindowsPowerShell/5.1.20348.859`.

Comment: Thanks for that @Jeff.